# How do I use the Java ServiceLoader class in Grails?

Tags: grails, serviceloader

I've used the JDK's [SPI mechanism](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) in numerous other applications without any problem; however, I can't seem to get it to work within Grails.

I've tried the usual code (shown below) both from within a static initializer, and from within a class constructor, but neither worked.

```
ServiceLoader loader = ServiceLoader.load(QueryEngine.class);
Iterator<QueryEngine> it = loader.iterator();
```

The iterator doesn't actually iterate through the implementing classes.

I've also tried:

```
ServiceLoader.load(QueryEngine.class, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

which should use the classloader for the current class, but that doesn't work either.

Is there some other mechanism I should be using to load implementing classes?

Comment: Do you have appropriate file in META-INF/services folder? It should be named like full name of interface/abstract class (for instance "example.QueryEngine") and contain all implementation of it (like "example.QueryEngineImpl").

Comment: Yes.  I can use the same classes in a Java program and it works without any problem.  Makes me wonder if there's a some kinda Grails classloader magic going on which hoses the ServiceLoader.

Comment: try using ServiceLoader.load(QueryEngine) and omit the .class. Otherwise you might just be loading the class Class